# I am unable to execute selenium code as my browser is quitting by showing null pointer exception

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, exception

```
[System] initializing MQSeleniumFW
[System] validation Status : false
[System initilaizing Logging properties]
MQFWToolInstance: 2386190563904
[System Logging properties successfully initilaized]
[System] Validating MQAppConnection Properties.
[System] MQAppConnection properties successfully initialized.
[System] Validating MQTestLinkConnection Properties
[System] MQTestLinkConnection properties successfully initialized
[System] Validating MQDBConnection Properties
[System] MQDBConnection properties successfully initialized
[System] Validating MQCaptureScreenShot Properties
[System] MQCaptureScreenShot properties successfully initialized
[System] MQSeleniumFW successfully initialized
[System] validation Status : true
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\poornima.medasani\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--309394340\testng-customsuite.xml

2019-04-25 07:24:43.420:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1325ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
Apr 25, 2019 7:24:43 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider getDriverClass
INFO: Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
Apr 25, 2019 7:24:43 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory registerDriverProvider
INFO: Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities {browserName: safari, platform: MAC, version: } does not match the current platform VISTA
Apr 25, 2019 7:24:43 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.SeleniumServer boot
INFO: Using the passthrough mode handler
2019-04-25 07:24:43.817:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.5.v20170502
2019-04-25 07:24:43.868:WARN:osjs.SecurityHandler:main: ServletContext@o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7c0c77c7{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
2019-04-25 07:24:43.877:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7c0c77c7{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2019-04-25 07:24:43.901:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@2e4b8173{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2019-04-25 07:24:43.902:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @1810ms
[System] Selenium Server booting completed. Server Started
Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 41012
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
302 test case runs when Stock points are disabled.
 else condition
entered
INV_329() method entered
In catchINV-2465
INV-24652
Test 342/2469 Passed in Issue on Requisition Note
Test 344/2471 Passed in Issue on Requisition Note
Test 345/2472 Passed in Issue on Requisition Note
Test 346/2473 Passed in Issue on Requisition Note
353 test case runs when Stock Points are disabled.
354 test case runs when Stock Points are disabled.
356 test case runs when Stock Points are disabled.
357 test case runs only when Stock Points are disabled.
3788 test case runs only when Stock Points are disabled.
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest afterTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mq.seleniumFW.MQSeleniumFW.closeAppBrowser(MQSeleniumFW.java:291)
    at mq.seleniumFW.MQSeleniumFW.afterTest(MQSeleniumFW.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:1012)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:636)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)

PASSED: INV_302
         Validate Inventory Location Combo 
PASSED: INV_345
        Validation on “Auto Approve Issue On Requisition” Privilege 
PASSED: INV_353
        Deleting the item details. Inventory items not repeated. 
PASSED: INV_354
         Editing the Shipped Quantity before saving the Transaction. 
PASSED: INV_356
        Verify the MQN- Issue with item status as Faulty and stock points set as No. 
PASSED: INV_357
        Verify the MQN- Issue with item status as Faulty and implicit MQN-transaction set as yes. 
PASSED: INV_3788
        Verify the Past date transactions in pending/approval. 
FAILED: INV_301
         Navigation for “ISSUE”(Material Requisition Note) 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mq.seleniumFW.utility.MQCaptureScreenShot.takeScreenShot(MQCaptureScreenShot.java:106)
    at Inventory_LogisticsTC.IssueOnRequisitionNoteTC.INV_301(IssueOnRequisitionNoteTC.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1130)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
FAILED: INV_355
        Verify the MQN- Issue with item status as Faulty and stock points set as Yes. 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mq.seleniumFW.utility.MQCaptureScreenShot.takeScreenShot(MQCaptureScreenShot.java:106)
    at Inventory_LogisticsTC.IssueOnRequisitionNoteTC.INV_355(IssueOnRequisitionNoteTC.java:2798)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1130)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)

FAILED: INV_4515
         Generating Issue for Multiple items with different quantity
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mq.seleniumFW.utility.MQCaptureScreenShot.takeScreenShot(MQCaptureScreenShot.java:106)
    at Inventory_LogisticsTC.IssueOnRequisitionNoteTC.INV_4515(IssueOnRequisitionNoteTC.java:3213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1130)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)


===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 53, Failures: 46, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 53, Failures: 46, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@12bb4df8: 79 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@11028347: 97 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@39a054a5: 41 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@512ddf17: 99 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@7960847b: 54 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 15 ms
```

Comment: I may not be able to answer your question, but hopefully others will. Try posting more info like your code, testng files, json files and it will help get others to answer your question.

Comment: can you format your code into blocks so it is more readable. I would check your version of chromedriver and chrome browser are matching. Chrome browser has updated recently.

Comment: Share some code containing the @AfterTest `afterTest` method.